# How do i detect swipe gestures in android stand-out library?

Tags: android, overlay, gesture, sidebar

I Require to use something like a swipe to bring up a sidebar which is always on top and i found out about standout which lets you create floating applications easily.
Now when implementing it I have started the floating app with id 1

```
   eventsBarServiceCB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
            {
                StandOutWindow.show(getApplicationContext(), SimpleWindow.class, 1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Starting Service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                StandOutWindow.close(getApplicationContext(), SimpleWindow.class,1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Stopping Service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

And in SimpleWindow

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchBody(int id, Window window, View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (id == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SimpleWindow",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else { // not touch edge
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not SimpleWindow",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            return false;
    }
```

But the problem with this code is 
!) No matter where I tap, only "SimpleWindow" toast is shown. "Not SimpleWindow" is never shown
2) I Do not know where to or how to put the swipe gesture